# Real time data on calls in queue

Tags: twilio

How can I see in real time (by the second) how many calls are in queue to be answered by an agent? Our current software shows if people are in queue to be answered by an agents which allows us to make sure all agents are helping out at that time. When testing, nothing in the dashboard in Twilio is informing me that callers are waiting to be answered by an agent. Ideally the same information would also be required for incoming calls into the IVR

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this TaskRouter API:

REST API: TaskQueue Statistics

https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/taskqueue-statistics